# Select2 onchange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

When I've added select2 to all selects in my app it worked very nice except when in my select is this property(it works when I don't use select2):

```
onchange="'refresh()'"
```

Function refresh:

```
function refresh()
{
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

This is how I run select2

```
    $("select").each(function(){
        var this1 = $(this);
        if(this1.attr('multiple')!='multiple')
        {
            this1.select2();
        }
    });
```

How to pass this? Or maybe there is some mechanism inside the select2 that deals with that kind of problems? All kinds of suggestions are welcome:D

Comment: Tell us WHAT doesn't work. Because it works fine here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/1878/)

Comment: I'm working on it, I'll give you some info in a couple minutes. btw thx for you response.

Comment: The select I'm using is from webwork. It worked good, for a long time, but adding a select2 to it makes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update this:

    `$(#Select/Input Element).select2();`

```
$("#select/input element").change(function () {
var valueToSet = $("#select/input element").select2('data').text;
$('#hiddent field to which data to be set').val(valueToSet);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Select/Input Element"? Could you explain that more precisely :)? I'm newbie in jQuery and javascript

Comment: Emil, when you use select2 with Ajax you need to use input element
and when you use select2 for select element in this case you are not using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand. When one of yours selects changes, you want to call the refresh method? In that case :

```
$("select").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.attr('multiple')!='multiple'){
        $this.select2();
        $this.change(refresh);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove single quote from **onchange="'refresh()'**. Try as mentioned below :

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="Refresh();"/>
```

And your script will be defined as below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function Refresh() {
            alert('refresh');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried that with my select, not with input. And still nothing.

Comment: can you update your question with the code which you are using ?